# How to fix PpstgreSQL-error "there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification"

Tags: postgresql

Running **PostgreSQL 15.4**, I have the following table:

```
create table public.topics
(
    id              serial constraint "PK_e4aa99a3fa60ec3a37d1fc4e853" primary key,
    created_at      timestamp         default now()                        not null,
    last_updated_at timestamp         default now(),
    uuid            varchar(64)                                            not null,
    stage           topics_stage_enum default 'dynamic'::topics_stage_enum not null,
    name            varchar(256)                                           not null 
                    constraint idx_unique_topics_topic unique,
    sanitized_name  varchar(256)                                           not null 
                    constraint idx_unique_topics_sanitized unique
);


create index "IDX_5422249b54115966f4676e3bcd"
    on public.topics (created_at);

create index "IDX_41a25cc9eb73ff4225afd9d5a2"
    on public.topics (last_updated_at);

create index "IDX_55e32ccadfd3178c768652ddeb"
    on public.topics (stage);

create index "IDX_1304b1c61016e63f60cd147ce6"
    on public.topics (name);

create index "IDX_9b7b898f847194409c53b1abc8"
    on public.topics (sanitized_name);
```

Now I want to perform multiple **upsert** operations using the `ON CONFLICT`-term:

```
INSERT INTO "topics"("created_at", "last_updated_at", "uuid", "stage", "name", "sanitized_name") 
VALUES (DEFAULT, DEFAULT, $1, $2, $3, $4) 
ON CONFLICT ( "name", "sanitized_name" ) 
DO UPDATE SET "name" = EXCLUDED."name", "sanitized_name" = EXCLUDED."sanitized_name", 
"uuid" = EXCLUDED."uuid", "stage" = EXCLUDED."stage"  
RETURNING "id", "created_at", "last_updated_at", "stage"
```

The SQL-statement was created by TypeORM. However, it doesn't work anyways thanks to the ON CONFLICT clause and gives the following error:

> there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT
> specification

There is already a unique key both on the column `name` and one on `sanitized_name` and to my current understanding, this should work as expected.

How to fix that?

Comment: Why are your indexes named that way?

Comment: Try adding a new UNIQUE INDEX over both columns `name` and `sanitized_name`.

Comment: @DanielA.White typeorm is doing this

Comment: @IVOGELOV at the end i only needed one unique key ("santized"-column) and then it works. thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try solving this error by creating a composite unique constraint that encompasses both "name" and "sanitized_name" columns as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE public.topics
ADD CONSTRAINT idx_unique_topics_name_sanitized UNIQUE (name, sanitized_name);
```

After that, change your INSERT statement so that the ON CONFLICT clause now references the new constraint:

```
INSERT INTO "topics"("created_at", "last_updated_at", "uuid", "stage", "name", "sanitized_name") 
VALUES (DEFAULT, DEFAULT, $1, $2, $3, $4) 
ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT idx_unique_topics_name_sanitized 
DO UPDATE SET "name" = EXCLUDED."name", "sanitized_name" = EXCLUDED."sanitized_name", 
"uuid" = EXCLUDED."uuid", "stage" = EXCLUDED."stage"  
RETURNING "id", "created_at", "last_updated_at", "stage";
```

Hope it works :)